# How can i get instagram account information

Tags: php, instagram

Good time
How can i give some information of a profile on instagram ?
I would like to give `Account type(Public, Private)` and `Follower Count` and if the entered username dose't available return an error with this message, for example `i can find page`.
How can i do it using **Faster** way with PHP ?
I test it but this is very slow! :

```
$otherPage = 'nasa';
$response = file_get_contents("https://www.instagram.com/$otherPage/?__a=1");
if ($response !== false) {
    $data = json_decode($response, true);
    if ($data !== null) {
        $follows = $data['user']['follows']['count'];
        $followedBy = $data['user']['followed_by']['count'];
        echo $follows . ' and ' . $followedBy;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add a code you have tried. By 'FASTER' you're implying that you already have an idea/code, but it's slow. Share those and you'd be set.

Comment: @RepeaterCreeper Sorry, code added

Answer (score 1):

You should use official api from [instagram](https://www.instagram.com/developer/).

1. [Authenticate](https://www.instagram.com/developer/authentication/)
2. Search for user [(at section endpoints)](https://www.instagram.com/developer/endpoints/users/#get_users)
3. Gets information about user [(at section endpoints)](https://www.instagram.com/developer/endpoints/users/#get_users_search)

You can use some external [library](https://github.com/cosenary/Instagram-PHP-API).